# Shortcut or button to toggle space or tab as subsequent indentation character in Notepad++?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, toolbar

I would like to have either a keyboard shortcut or a toolbar button that toggles if I use tabs (ie <kbd>tab</kbd> for indentation) or make `notepad++` use spaces instead.

It would be a nice extra if a toolbar button could be added to toggle showing whitespace characters on/off, but no new lines.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When toggling space/tabs for indentation, would you like the change to only apply to future indentation or all indents, including already existing ones?

### To Convert All Existing Spaces to Tabs and Vice Versa

**Hotkey**: Settings -> Shortcut Mapper -> Main Menu and set hotkeys for the TAB to Space and vice options

**Toolbar Button**: Install plugin "Customize Toolbar" from Plugins -> Plugin Manager. After installation, Plugins -> Customize Toolbar -> Customize will allow you to add the "Tab to Space" and "Space to Tab" buttons

### Toggle indentation character (space or tab) for subsequent indents

- Install the **Python Script** plugin and from its menu, **Create new script**.
- Choose a file name and save *in the given directory*
- In the blank script file add: `editor.setUseTabs(not editor.getUseTabs())` and save

From the Python Script -> Configuration menu:

**Hotkey**: Add a menu item and restart N++. From Shortcut Mapper -> Plugin Commands, set a shortcut for your toggle script.

**Button**: Add a button. Restart N++. If the toolbar button is not clickable, a conflict with the **Customize Toolbar** plugin is occuring, so you might have to remove that plugin. If there is a way to get  **Customize Toolbar** and  **Python Script**  to add buttons to the toolbar simultaneously, I haven't found it.

### Toggling Whitespace Character Visibility

**Hotkey**: Shortcut Mapper -> Main Menu -> "Show Whitespace and Tab"
or

Set **Hotkey** and/or **Toolbar Button** for the following N++ Python Script:

```
# Toggle whitespace visibilty through the following modes
# 0: The normal display mode with white space displayed as an empty background colour
# 1: White space characters are drawn as dots and arrows
# 2: White space used for indentation is displayed normally but after the first visible character, it is shown as dots and arrows
# 
# Mode descriptions from http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_GETVIEWWS

editor.setViewWS( (editor.getViewWS()+1)%3 )
```

Comment: I've set a keyboard shortcut for the "subsequent_indents toggler", but every time I use it and then switch to another file tab and back, the setting is reset (without me doing anything). any ideas?

Comment: Nice work protongun. @naxa: I assume this is because it reloads the tab setting from the per-filetype setting (Settings > Preferences > Tab Settings > Filetype > Replace by space). Do you want a script which toggles this global setting? Might be the only way.

Comment: @NigelTouch it's a plausible theory, yes. I have no idea how to toggle the global 'replace by tab' setting, yet.

Comment: In Notepad++ how can I make a tab be displayed as an arrow instead of as 4 dots?